# Does a .wav file created from a .mp3 file have better quality than the .mp3 file itself?

Tags: frequency, sound, mp3

A .wav file created from a .mp3 file has the same frequency domain plot as the mp3 file itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58706674/difference-between-frequency-domain-in-mp3-and-wav.

However, the .wav file created from .mp3 file has larger file size. According the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593806/why-is-a-wav-file-created-from-a-mp3-file-much-larger-in-size, this is because the .wav file is storing much more data than the mp3 file is.

Now, is there any difference in the quality between the .wav file and .mp3 file?

Does the quality of .wav file sound better since it has more data stored?

Comment: mp3 format is a compression method. It loses data which is supposed to be insignificant to the human ear. This means that no quality degradation is introduced. However, some listeners report that they do feel quality degradation. In any case, the conversion from  mp3 back to wav cannot reinvent the lost information. If anything, any conversion process is a risk of introducing more noise (depending on the process). So, no, the quality of wav converted from mp3 is not better.

Comment: Thanks @havakok. If so, what is the purpose of mp3 decoder since nowadays many devices do support mp3 format?

Comment: The purpose is compression.

Comment: @Cyan "Amount of data" and "quality of data" are not always correlated. I can take lossy compressed data, stuff it with a bunch of random numbers to increase the "amount of data", but (as I hope you can see) the quality of the original data has not increased.

Answer (score 4):

MP3 is a lossy compression format, so encoding an uncompressed lossless WAV file to MP3 will lose some quality in the encoding process.

Decoding a MP3 file back to WAV file has at most the same quality as the MP3 file has, it is just as good or bad as the contents in the MP3 file was, it is not in any way different to decode it for saving into a file or decoding it for playback. Most importantly, you don't get the lost quality back when decoding, and basically the result actually depends on the quality of the decoder as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well... maybe.

MP3 in its standard use is an a lossy audio compression format. It uses human auditory models to degrades data which the human ear is not (totally) sensitive too. Some sounds actually present in the audio file will not be heard because they are below the threshold of hearing, or they are masked by other sounds, nearby in time or frequency. This information that can be discarded is used to reduce the necessary size in bits to store the audio content.

So, information is lost, and a direct conversion to another audio format, whether lossless or not, will only cause minor changes (because of floating points operations on data and rounding, etc.). Unless in extreme cases (very high compression, very quiet sounds), those are unlikely to be heard.

However, compression standard tell how to decode compressed file streams, and do not disallow postprocessing that can improve the objective or subjective quality of the compressed file. For instance, an image renderer can process a decoded JPEG image to smooth out some border/checkerboard artifacts. The same may occur in audio, eg [DSP-based audio post processing enhances audio quality](https://www.eetimes.com/dsp-based-audio-post-processing-enhances-audio-quality/). Based on some models, some processing  might be able to compensate for what was lost in the initial MP3 coding.

Last: when original audio data contains noise, surprisingly, compression can enhance the quality, as noise can be discarded first while compressing. This is described in the influential paper (at least to me) [Filtering Random Noise from Deterministic Signals via Data Compression](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/78.482110) by Natarajan in 1995.
So, it is not impossible that converting a lossy format into another lossy format may actually improve quality.

Comment: That's a nice explanation with some nice papers presented, thanks. Although I do believe that the post-processing you mention cannot restore what was lost since this is lost. It may enhance the sound of the audio file in one way or another, but from the technical point of view, I don't know of any processing that could restore the discarded information. Please let me know if I am wrong in this, as it would interest me quite a lot to get to know more on that. Thanks again for the nice post.

Comment: I agree: if you consider a sound as an arbitrary waveform, with any possible value, ensuring recovery is hopeless. Indeed, if one believe that nature is continuous, ANY quantization would loose information. However, most digital sounds already went through physical devices and electronic media. Hence, the best "digital signal" you can recover belongs to a far more limited "space of possibilities". Think about Nyquist-Shannon: band-limited discrete sampling can recover a continuous waveform. So, using additional hypotheses, one may except better recovery.

Comment: However, most optimization algorithms deal with imprecise computations. So you cannot hope to recover "the full initial precision", but you can get better that what was compressed

Answer (score 0):

Changing an MP3 to wave file does not effect  the content of the file
If you wish to remaster or adjust the file content then changing the file to wave
will give results
Such as:
changing to a wave 96k/ 24 bit and adding a tape vst then back to MP3 at its original
Rate or at least 320 bit rate
A little practice and the use of multiple vst  it is possible to eliminate
or greatly reduce the so called MP3  artifacts
Even after changing back to MP3.
A use of a audio host as well as a vst chainer you can listen in real time
as well as process your file .

Answer (score 0):

There is only one correct way to decode an MP3, it is a deterministic process, and since WAV is a lossless audio format, using it as an intermediate does not change the signal. Which means the answer is a clear no.
The signal distortion happening in the MP3 encoding process can not be reversed, some information from the source is always permanently lost.